# data.table fread does not see "^M" as new line any more

Tags: r, data.table

The data.table issue report site cautious us about frivolous reports. Can somebody running version 1.11.4 confirm this fread problem for me before I report t?

We have an older script that worked without complications to import some CSV files distributed from Qualtrics.  These Qualtrics files, which I am not allowed to show you now, have gitantic complicated strings with embedded carriage returns in the first 100s of lines. I have a minimum reproducible example, however.  R's read.csv fails miserably, somehow data.table fread has always been the champion. The Qualtrics file has variable names in row1, then the questions themselves are typed into the next row(s).  There are carriage returns placed at random in the middle of the questions (pasted from MS Word files, probably).

Today we noticed that fread no longer works. I've just tested this several times, installing data.table 1.10.4-3 (which worked without trouble) and the current 1.11.4 which does cause the problem.  The symptom of the issue with my minimal reproducible example is

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.11.4  Latest news: http://r-datatable.com
> fread("dt-test.csv")
   id,y,x1,x2\rRespondentidentification,      "An
1:                            variable", "Working
2:                               input",    "more
                                  outcome
1:                                     on
2: input"\rResp1,33,22,33\rResp2,31,19,32
Warning message:
In fread("dt-test.csv") :
  Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.
```

When you inspect the troublesome CSV file, you see Qualtrics provides a row 2 that has embedded carriage returns in the middle of quoted strings. Those things cause R's read.csv to fail, why I started using fread in the first place.  However, in the trouble file there are Windows carriage return symbols, "^M" where we expect the actual new lines. If I manually replace those with "^M" carriage returns, then problem is solved.

Now, about my MRE. When I try to paste it in here, the "^M" new line symbols get turned into new lines! So I put in "^M" literal where the symbol should be. This mimics the bad structure of the Qualtrics file:

```
id,y,x1,x2^MRespondentidentification, "An outcome 
variable", "Working on
input", "more input"^MResp1,33,22,33^MResp2,31,19,32
```

I put a copy of the minimal test file here:  http://pj.freefaculty.org/scraps/dt-test.csv
in case one of you brave souls is willing to test to confirm

I just noticed that LibreOffice opens that file and it recognizes the "^M" as new lines and it protects the carriage returns in the middle of line 2.

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.11.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4
```

Comment: You should report this as an issue. If you don't mind, please provide the expected output in addition to your reprex. Thank you.